I swapped a token using uniswap bot, I have unrealised profits but I no longer have the position
I swapped a token using uniswap bot, I have unrealised profits but I no longer have the position. it shows me as if I have zero balance in my account.
here is my transaction on etherscan:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9e1a1284924b8ff50f88b1410c6691e893ed78b27b33777686e29e4f9f5438a1
Is there a way I can get my money back?

Hey this is a common scam, where the deployer has some obfuscated function (openTrading in this case), that reduces the balance of a holder, and they just repeatedly zero the balances of buyers.
Scammers will wash trade to appear in the top of dextools trending lists so be careful what you trust, get comfortable reading through and testing the contracts if they have no real history.
People were having their balances removed as you purchased so it was there to see.
Yours is removed a few blocks after your purchase: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x177360a076ef2fffebb76a53c1933025552b9ce6bea4f20faa7486a6cbfa0d76
